# Having issue with this preg_replace()

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I've been battling with this code for two days now, and I've searched so many related post without any clue. Please I need help.
The code:

```
$string = "Hello, can you please come here?"
$t = preg_replace('/[^.,:;?!@a-zA-Z0-9 \'\-]/', '', $string);
```

This code works perfectly matching all the characters except comma(,). Suppose the value passed to the 't' is - **Hello, can you please come?**
The output I always get is - **Hello can you please come?** without the comma(,).
Please I need help on how to match the comma, as comma is the second character in the preg_replace above.

Comment: Is that comma a specific, non-ASCII, comma?

Comment: Yes, the comma within the bracket is part of the characters I want to match.

Comment: When I use this preg_replace on any text statement, for example "Hey, somebody come here!" The comma after "Hey" is stripped off.

Comment: Is your input a Unicode string? Add `/u` modifier. I tried with your input, and [cannot repro](http://ideone.com/YikKLL).

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong with the regex, [it correctly matches everything](https://regex101.com/r/XwNofZ/1) (thus ignoring it correctly in your case). *Noting that I copied and pasted your string and regex.*

Comment: Have to agree, the sample you've presented works as would normally be expected. **Have you looked at the source of the data?** There are escape sequences for comma -- `&#44;` . Print your input (from database or wherever) straight into the source code. Execute page and view source (not inspect element) and see what it's actually printing. **Also, just a tip:** append a + after the class to do less iterations of the replace (if it happens to find two non-matching in a row. `[^.,:;?!@a-zA-Z0-9 \'\-]+`

Comment: Thanks guys, sanitizing my variables before updating them in the database resolved the issue.